# ATG | After query result getPropertyValue() function is hitting DB

Tags: atg

1. I have a repository which can not be cached.
2. I built a query to return the matching RepositoryItem[]
3. After getting RepositoryItem[] from query I'm iterating over it.
4. But here in every iteration when I use getPropertyValue() it hits the DB

Here is the solutions I tried: (tried 3 ways to load data eagerly)

1. [Using Eager Loading](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41069_01/Platform.11-0/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s1016lazyloadingsettings01.html#s1016itemdescriptorloadingstrategyatt01)

also I tried to created the group of properties but after getting RepositoryItem[] I don't want to hit the DB again.

Please point me towards the way to achieve this.
Thnx,,,

Comment: I think you need to enable caching for the item.

Comment: Thnx, but caching is something I can not use for my repository (I need to get the data from DB every time)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491136/atg-repositoryitem-getpropertyvalue-no-cache-no-transaction?rq=1